# webview causing app to crash

Tags: java, android

Im working on an app for Overclock.net and im having a webview problem. The class causes the application to stop.  this is my code

```
 package nathan.ocnuo.util;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.webkit.WebView;
  import nathan.ocnuo.R;


public class web extends Activity {

private WebView mWebView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.overclock.net/t/1019761/overclock-net-app/30");
}
```

**text.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";  
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <WebView xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; 
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

**Logcat**

```
 01-19 22:07:57.378 32438-32438/nathan.ocnuo E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: nathan.ocnuo, PID: 32438 ava.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity at
android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3851) at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4466) at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18552) at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
```

Im very confused. Any help is appreciated:) sorry if this post is annoying...

Comment: where is your logcat then?

Comment: Sorry without it we can't help you.

Comment: give me a minute i have the droid turbo to test on and the drivers dont like to work. ill find a way

Comment: 01-19 22:07:57.378  32438-32438/nathan.ocnuo E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: 01-19 22:07:57.378  32438-32438/nathan.ocnuo E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: nathan.ocnuo, PID: 32438
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3851)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4466)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18552)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)

Comment: show me your test.xml file

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>

Comment: from your code there is no error in this activity. error may be in another activity and have you added INTERNET permission in manifest file?

Comment: yes i think so.     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
right?

Comment: Please include full stacktrace, including the nested "caused by" exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have added Internet permission in your manifest file as below:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```